# Im trying to use sudo apt update but keep getting this error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

Ive been trying to run sudo apt update but I keep running to the same error which ive added below. I'll appreciate any input you have

```
E: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease/dists/jammy/InRelease jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```